# NSDate and UIDatepicker Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar

I am exercising in `Swift`, experimenting with `Dates`. 
I made an app that shows the current date, then I add days to that date by inserting them to the `NSCalendar` component.

All of that works just fine, by adding a day I get the next day.
My problem is that I have a `UIDatePicker` that shows only time. I'm trying to insert the given by me hour and minute but instead I am adding those numbers to the future date because it keeps the same hour and minute as of the current date.

**So my questions are:**

- Is there a way to get the current date and then somehow change it's hour and minute values to 0?
- Is it possible to replace the future time's hour and minute values to the ones that I give through the UIDatePicker?

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to be able to add future events to a calendar at a time that I want to and not at a future date with a time the same as the time I am about to add the event.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: You can use NSCalendar method dateBySettingHour and set the desired time or if you want the first time of the day you can use startOfDayForDate. Just keep in mind that it is not necessarily 12am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSCalendar` class:

```
let date = NSDate() // date with current time
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date2 = calendar.dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: date, options: []) // date with zero time
```

Comment: This is somewhat working but as @leo said, that's not necessarily 12am and gives me a time of 22:00. I have to 
let date2 = calendar.dateBySettingHour(**2**, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: date, options: []) 
which is somewhat only correct for my timeZone and breaks after the time changes. +-1 hour (2 times per year).

Comment: I guess that there's no problem if I set the hour on 0 though. The difference is only shown when I print the date whereas the calendar registers the correct hour.